# How to check in WiX, if IIS-Feature is installed?

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.8

I have programmed a Bootstrapper-project with WiX 3.8, in which i'm installing IIS Express 8.0 and activating some IIS-Features.
The activation lies in a seperate WXS-file - including a lot of ExePackages - like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Fragment>
  <PackageGroup Id='ActivateIisFeatures'>
    <ExePackage Id='IIS_WebserverRole'
                DisplayName='Installing IIS: IIS-WebServerRole'
                PerMachine='yes'
                SourceFile='.\Resources\Dism.exe'
                InstallCommand='/Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole'>
    </ExePackage>
    ...
  </PackageGroup>
  ...
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Now my problem is, that by this way, the ExePackages will be installed and the features activated everytime, the setup is installed or repaired.
So i tried the DetectCondition-Property.
You know, if the DetectCondition returns false, the Bootstrapper plans to install the ExePackage.
But the following edit does still install the ExePackages everytime, even when the features are active.

What have i to do, that the IIS-features will only installed/activated, when they are not active?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i have found it out myself.
It's really simple.
DetectCondition doesn't work here.
We have to search for the registrykey and check the result in the Installcondition of the ExePackage.
Most of the keys are lying in the folder "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components".
And there is a list on the iis-site, but it's old and not complete:
http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/discover-installed-components

Per example:

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components"
                     Value="W3SVC"
                     Variable="WebServer"/>

<ExePackage Id='IIS_WebServer'
            DisplayName='Installing IIS: IIS-WebServer'
            PerMachine='yes'
            SourceFile='.\Resources\Dism.exe'
            InstallCondition='NOT WebServer'
            InstallCommand='/Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer'>
</ExePackage>
```

By this way, once a features was activated, it doesn't happen anymore while reinstalling or repairing the setup.

Comment: I don't think you can do this.  That would make dism.exe a redistributable which would fail on different versions of windows.